# JavaScript clear timeout not working with React useEffect return function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout

For some reason, I need to call `checkProgess` function for the first 2 minutes with 10 seconds of delays.

So I did it like this

```
const [timers, setTimers] = useState<ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>[]>([]);

useEffect(()=>{
 for (let index = 0; index < 12; index++) {
      const seconds = (index+1)*10000;
    
      let timer = setTimeout(() => {
       
          checkProgress(id, setFieldValue, contractType, fileOCRStatus);
       
      }, seconds);
      console.log("timer",timer)
      setTimers((prev) => {
        prev.push(timer)
        return prev
      });
    }

},[])
```

within these 12 tries, this component will unmount if the progress checks succeed. In that time I do want to clear all the remaining timeout calls. I did it like this in the `useEffect` return function.

```
 return () => {
      console.log("Return function called",timers)
      timers.forEach((timer) => clearTimeout(timer));
     
    };
```

This part is executed successfully but the cleaning thing seems not working. I CAN SEE THE API CALLS RUNNING AFTER THE COMPONENT IS UNMOUNTED.

what went wrong here?
In `console.log("Return function called", timers)` timer ids also print correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to store these in a state since this `useEffect` is only running once (and even if it wasn't, since you're cleaning up the timers in the returned function, you don't need to keep the value across renders).

```js
// delete the useState stuff

useEffect(() => {
  const timers = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < 12; index++) {
    const seconds = (index+1)*10000;
    
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      checkProgress(id, setFieldValue, contractType, fileOCRStatus);
    }, seconds);
    console.log("timer",timer)
    timers.push(timer);
  }

  return () => {
    timers.forEach((timer) => clearTimeout(timer));
  }
}, []);
```